# Exercises of aplication of Green's theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Use Green's Theorem to find the limited area above the $x$-axis and below the circle of centers $C_1(0,1)$ and $C_2(2,1)$, both of radio equal to $1$.

$C_1: x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ and $C_2: (x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=1$

I am a bit confused on how to use this theorem the proposed problem, can you help me?

Comment: your equations of circles are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Calculus Vol.2 Tom Apostol](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Apostol%20-%20CALCULUS%20-%20VOLUME%202%20-%20Multi%20Variable%20Calculus%20and%20Linear%20Algebra,%20with%20Applications%20to%20Differential%20Equations%20and%20Probability.pdf) page 383.

Answer (score 0):

Use Green's theorem to the field $\vec{F}=\langle -y,x \rangle$. Parametrise the Boundary curve.